# Mod_rewrite handling extra get variables (QSA not working)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a mod rewrite rule for settings page: (localhost/settings/index.php)

```
RewriteRule settings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And I am handling menu references within the URL which will be similar to:

```
http://localhost/settings/xyz/?ref=menu1&abc=2&de=3..
```

However, with my current rewrite rule, the variable does not get passed along and I didn't get the values of ref,abc..

I read [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) about QSA flag but that doesn't seem to be working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning off `MultiViews` option:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^settings/([\w-]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

---

In place of `QSA`, you can use this trick to captured query string:

```
RewriteRule ^settings/([\w-]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Nopes, Still same result. receiving the resultant url as `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc` on passing `http://localhost/settings/abc/?ref=1`

Comment: ok I need some more info. What's the URL you're using to test? Are there more rules in your .htaccess? Does `settings/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: URL is: `http://localhost/settings/abc/?ref=1&abc=2&..` which should render like `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=1&abc=2&..`. This is the only rule I am using in `.htaccess` and No, there's just one `.htaccess` in root, i.e (http://localhost/).

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: Its `Apache/2.4.18`

Comment: Awesome! that worked. But I am curious why did QSA didn't work?

Comment: Even I'm baffled. First time I've seen this problem of `QSA` not working.

Comment: And magically `QSA` started working on my project! when I used this `RewriteRule settings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`. Still leaves the question! how? :D But still doesn't work here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Don't test on that site, always better to test with your local Apache installation.