# PHP - URL with multiple parameters and same name causing unexpected behaviour

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, parameters, get

I have a Rewrite Rule as

```
RewriteRule settings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

It basically takes path parameter and rewrite url like this
`http://localhost/settings/?path=abc` => `http://localhost/settings/abc`

But there's a problem! when I provide something like `http://localhost/settings/abc/?path=xyz` the path parameter is overwritten with xyz and it opens `http://localhost/settings/abc/` with data of `xyz`

After further digging I noticed that the problem is caused by the parameters in URL itself. By default its picking up the value of last parameter with same name `http://localhost/settings/account/?path=profile&path=account&path=profile`

so the value that i can get in this case for `$_REQUEST['path']` is `profile`. How can I just pickup the first value from the same parameters and ignore the rest of them?

One thing I can do is to remove `[QSA]` from the `RewriteRule`, that will do the fix but I need other parameters passed in url as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just use a big! random string in the rewrite too keep the change of overiding small.

Comment: @JOUM I didn't really understand what you tried to convey

Comment: `But there's a problem! ...` can be fixed with this (internally use only, the possiblilty to override this value is little vurnebule for you application). But the part `After further digging` is onther issue on your side, because you should prevent url like this in first place (repeated use of same names for arguments).

Comment: Just use: `RewriteRule ^settings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Hi @anubhava I was waiting for your reply and I thought you remembered this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39904015/1681154 :)

Comment: Yes, I do remember but I thought having multiple parameters with the same name is a different problem.

Comment: Yes, it is different. can't we restrict the parameter value (with same name) as the first value in the parameter list but with also accepting other query string params?

Answer (score 2):

PHP recognizes brackets `[]` appended to a parameter, e.g.

```
http://localhost/settings/account/?path[]=profile&path[]=account&path[]=profile
```

will be translated into an array

```
$path = $_GET['path'];
print_r($path);
```

shows

> Array ( [0] => profile [1] => account [2] => profile )

This way, you can access any of the "paths" you like.

---

I could imagine some [`RewriteCond`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) surgery, in order to remove part of a query string

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&path=.*?&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1&%2

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^path=.*?&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&path=.*$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1
```

Depending on where the `path` is, this would remove it from the query string. And finally, the last rule would add the new path again

```
RewriteRule settings/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$ settings/?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Although, I don't know, if this is working at all, and how (in)efficient this is.

There is one caveat, you must check for `REDIRECT_STATUS` to prevent an endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That will do the job, but my question is that can't we just restrict the value to first parameter if there are multiple parameters with same name? I just need  one and first value but instead its just overwriting and picking the last value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these 2 rules in your .htaccess:

```
# remove path= parameter from query string, if it exists
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?path=[^&]*(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^settings/. %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=301,NE,NC]

# your existing rule
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?(.*&)?path=[^&]*(?:&(\S*))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^settings/ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [L,R=302,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)path= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(settings)/(\w*)/?$ $1/?path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Great that works if I use rewrite URL `http://localhost/settings/abc?path=xyz&ref=menu` but fails on this condition `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=menu`

Comment: And if I use something like this `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=menu` it redirects to `http://localhost/settings/?ref=menu%20HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Ah I made a mistake in first rule. Try my updated rules now.

Comment: If I use only 3rd RewriteCond i.e. `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)path= [NC]`  
`RewriteRule ^(settings)/(\w*)/?$ $1/?path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]` It works perfect on URL like this `http://localhost/settings/abc?path=xyz&ref=menu` takes `path=abc` and `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=menu` again takes `path=abc` but it fails on `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&path=xyz&ref=menu` takes `xyz`

But first 2 cases simply remove all the path parameters and do a redirect. 

In case of `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=menu&path=xyz` I need at most 1 path (first one) as `path=abc`

Comment: And that's indeed a brilliant solution! but just got stuck in one condition like this: `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&ref=menu&path=xyz` :)

Comment: `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&path=xyz&ref=menu` is already an invalid URL since it has 2 parameters with same name. Rules can help to avoid making it invalid but you cannot start with an invalid URL. btw from where are you getting this URL `http://localhost/settings/?path=abc&path=xyz&ref=menu` ?